Virtual serial port - Windows
I'm using compiled version of socat for windows - https://github.com/tech128/socat-1.7.3.0-windows, and tried to open connection between two ptys
 ./socat.exe -d -d -x PTY,raw,link=/c/test/tty1 PTY,raw,link=/c/test/tty2 but it looks like the tunnel is not bidirectional. How to correctly open virtual serial in windows ?
 ./socat.exe -d -d -x PTY,raw,link=/c/test/tty1 PTY,raw,link=/c/test/tty2

There seems to be a newer version here, so why not give it a try? valorisa/socat-1.8.0.0_for_Windows
